# How can I set the length of the MRU plugin?

Tags: vimrc

I'm using https://github.com/yegappan/mru

I remember in the past having an option to set the length of the list, but can't find it now?i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by length, but in the [documentation](https://github.com/yegappan/mru/wiki/User-Manual), there seem to be multiple properties that could be what you're looking for:

- `MRU_Window_Height`
- `MRU_Max_Entries`

They can be set like so:

```
let MRU_Window_Height = 40
```